# doctrine2 querybuilder not between

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'd like to make a MySQL query with doctrine2 QueryBuilder (Symfony 3.4 app) with a `NOT BETWEEN` statment.

The doctrine provide a `->expr()->between(..)` but not `->expr()->notBetween(..)`

Is there a way to negate the between with the query builder.

I don't want to use a native or a DQL query if possible.

Note: I think a possible solution is to use `->expr()->lt(..)` and/or `->expr()->gt(..)` but I want to know if `notBetween` is possible.

Thanks

Expected:

A `NOT BETWEEN` SQL statement with Doctrine2 QueryBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempts, I found a suitable solution for me:

The QueryBuilder provide a `->expr()->not(...)`, so in this case this is possible:

`$qb->exp()->not($qb->between('field', 'from', 'to')`

SQL result:
`NOT (BETWEEN field from AND TO)`